# Are Android's BroadcastReceivers started in a new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, broadcastreceiver

If I have an inner class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` within my `Service` class, should I care about synchronization, when the `BroadcastReceiver` class reads/writes to objects from the `Service` class?
Or to put it in another way: Are `BroadacstReceiver`'s `onReceive()` Methods started in an extra thread?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The onReceive() method is always called on the main thread (which is also referred to as "UI thread"), unless you requested it to be scheduled on a different thread using the registerReceiver() variant:

```
Context.registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver,
                         IntentFilter filter,
                         String broadcastPermission,
                         Handler scheduler)
```

Comment: What about LocalBroadcastManager? Why no such method?

Answer (score 27):

> Are Android's BroadcastReceivers started in a new thread?

Usually but not always, it all depends on how you register it.

If you register your `BroadcastReceiver` using:

```
registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)
```

It will run in the ***main activity thread(aka UI thread)***.

If you register your `BroadcastReceiver` using a valid `Handler` running on a different thread:

```
registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler)
```

It will run in the context of your ***`Handler`***

For example:

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("ht");
handlerThread.start();
Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, null, handler); // Will not run on main thread
```

Details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29) & [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29).

Comment: Caner. So operation of *Toast.makeText(..data)* in `onReceive` where *data* is passed from a background thread in service is thread safe?

Answer (score 18):

[The onReceive() method is called on the main thread.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) So, in case all your access to the service class is done from within the main thread, you don't need any synchronization.

Comment: So the answer to his question is no! The `onReceive` method does not run on an extra thread.

Comment: Android Cookbook:
Be aware that the BroadcastReceiver runs on the same thread that the intent is Broadcast on; in our example this is the main/GUI thread!

Comment: @Stephan, so operation of *Toast.makeText(..data)* in  `onReceive` where *data* is passed  from a background thread in service  is thread safe?

Answer (score 3):

Android Broadcast receivers are by default start in GUI thread (main thread) if you use
 `RegisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter).`

But it can be run in a worker thread as follows;

When using a HandlerThread, be sure to exit the thread after unregistering the BroadcastReceiver. If not, File Descriptor (FD) leaks occur in Linux level and finally the application gets crashed if continue to Register / Unregister.

unregisterReceiver(...);

Then 
looper.quit(); 
Or 
looper.quitSafely();

```
private Handler broadcastReceiverHandler = null;
private HandlerThread broadcastReceiverThread = null;
private Looper broadcastReceiverThreadLooper = null;

private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverReadScans = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }
}

private void registerForIntents() {
    broadcastReceiverThread = new HandlerThread("THREAD_NAME");//Create a thread for BroadcastReceiver
    broadcastReceiverThread.start();

    broadcastReceiverThreadLooper = broadcastReceiverThread.getLooper();
    broadcastReceiverHandler = new Handler(broadcastReceiverThreadLooper);

    IntentFilter filterScanReads = new IntentFilter();
    filterScanReads.addAction("ACTION_SCAN_READ");
    filterScanReads.addCategory("CATEGORY_SCAN");

    context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverReadScans, filterScanReads, null, broadcastReceiverHandler);
}

private void unregisterIntents() {
    context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverReadScans);
    broadcastReceiverThreadLooper.quit();//Don't forget
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can specify the "android:process" receiver element attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html). That way you can specify that the receiver runs as a separate process and isn't tied to the main UI thread.