# Register a broadcast receiver from a service in a new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver, scheduler

I have a broadcastreciever which start a long operation (uploading process).
In the code of a service started from the Activity class, I need to register this receiver in a new thread.

I have checked this post [Are Android's BroadcastReceivers started in a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394950/are-android-broadcastreceiver-started-in-a-new-thread) but I need a more concrete example about using Context.registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter, String broadcastPermission, Handler scheduler)

Actually I need to know how to create a new thread from a service and to register the receiver and attached to this thread.

Thank you very much.
RA

Comment: please elaborate if possible add some code

Comment: read comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394950/are-android-broadcastreceiver-started-in-a-new-thread post you will get answer no it's not possible bez onRecive method is called in main thread

Comment: Hi Aashish, Thanks for your remark. I am actually asking for code :) I do not know exactly how to register a broadcast receiver in a new thread. I need an example if it is possible. I have searching on the net on how to do that but I could not find such example. What I understood is that 1) we have to create a new thread and 2) a handler for this thread and then 3) register the receiver in the new thread using the handler. Can someone give me a short example or explanation about how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your service's `onCreate()`:

```
private Handler handler; // Handler for the separate Thread

HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyNewThread");
handlerThread.start();
// Now get the Looper from the HandlerThread so that we can create a Handler that is attached to
//  the HandlerThread
// NOTE: This call will block until the HandlerThread gets control and initializes its Looper
Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
// Create a handler for the service
handler = new Handler(looper);
// Register the broadcast receiver to run on the separate Thread
registerReceiver (myReceiver, intentFilter, broadcastPermission, handler);
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much! it is working now :) I really appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Note: I got an error telling me that Handler(looper, this) is undefined and that I have to delete "this" argument or the cast it to Callback. I deleted this argument and it is working. Thank you. RA

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I had copied this code from one of my services and that service implemented the handleMessage() callback itself. That's why the `this` parameter was there. Glad to be of assistance.