# Android service does not react on intent

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I'm trying to make my first service with LocalBroadcastManager and BroadcastReceiver. Service starts but it doesnt react on intent that is sent to it. Really I dont know what is wrong I have tried every possible way.

This is how i start service with intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, VikimgService.class);
    i.setAction(VikimgService.ACTION);
    startService(i);
```

Annotation in manifest

```
<service android:name="pl.alemac.vikimg.service.VikimgService" />
```

Its my service

```
public class VikimgService extends Service {

public static final String ACTION = "pl.alemac.vikimg.service.VikimgService.action";
public static final String REACTION = "pl.alemac.vikimg.service.VikimgService.reaction";
public static final String REREACTION = "pl.alemac.vikimg.service.VikimgService.rereaction";

private String user;
private Looper sServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler sServiceHandler;
private long mHandlerThreadId;

private class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        onHandleIntent((Intent) msg.obj, msg.arg1);
    }
}

void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent, int id) {
    if (Thread.currentThread().getId() != mHandlerThreadId) {
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
    }
    String test = intent.getAction();
    if (test.equals(ACTION)) {
        Log.d("test", "onHandleIntent called ACTION");
        Intent in = new Intent();
        in.setAction(REACTION);
        in.putExtra("user", user);
        Log.d("test", "sending broadcast REACTION");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(in);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    user = "test333";

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("pl.alemac.vikimg.service.VikimgService");
    thread.start();
    mHandlerThreadId = thread.getId();
    sServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    sServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(sServiceLooper);

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e("test", "service destroyed");
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

after changing method onStartCommand to pasted below I achieved what I wanted to do - there is a communication between service and activity, I dont know if its perfect solution but it works.

Interesting approach to the topic is posted here -> [Register a broadcast receiver from a service in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682241/register-a-broadcast-receiver-from-a-service-in-a-new-thread)

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
String test = intent.getAction();
if (test.equals(ACTION)) {
    Log.d("test", "onHandleIntent called ACTION");
    Intent in = new Intent();
    in.setAction(REACTION);
    in.putExtra("user", user);
    Log.d("test", "sending broadcast REACTION");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(in);
}
return START_STICKY;
```

}

Comment: why dont u try to  register your intent action in manifest using intent filter with your service tag

Comment: What do you mean the service starts but doesn't react to intent?

Comment: @Vivek Bajpai  I make it like <service android:name="pl.alemac.vikimg.service.VikimgService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="pl.alemac.vikimg.service.VikimgService.action" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service> and it does not work either

Comment: @Mike -> By saying this, i mean that service has been started because toast has been shown and handleMessage onHandleIntent is not called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `onHandleIntent` is only available in an `IntentService`, you are extending a `Service`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but i use ServiceHandler which extends Handler and I am using handler's handleMessage to process intent's action. So if i am doing it wrong, could you show me better approach?

Comment: Depends what you need your `Service` to do?

Comment: Ok, my service should keep data when my app will be in the background so it wouldnt be garbage-collectored like it did when i kept them in Application class. So by calling service I wish to retrive services properties use them and modify and send them back to service.

Comment: It sounds to me like you should use a database to persist your data. Or maybe save it as preferences. I don't think services should be alive for the sole purpose of storing data.

Comment: Oh well, maybe you are right after all. But in my app i still need to use service. I need it to keep my XMPP connection alive. So i would use the same 'sceleton' service but only actions will be different- connecting or disconnecting from the server.

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked with XMPP or anything similar. Can't help you with that.

Comment: No problem. I know how to manage connection, my app works when its in foreground but it crashes sometimes while its in background. So the biggest problem now is creating a service.

Comment: Could you please select the answer as correct? And maybe post a new question regarding your specific problem with keeping the XMPP connection alive?